# Morse Code Flash Timing

Tags: java, android

I'm fairly new to Java, and really new to Android development.
I am trying to make a Morse Code app, which will flash the user's entered message in Morse Code on the device's screen.
My problem is that I cannot find a way to pause the code to put the timings in.
I know that putting a wait() or sleep() straight in is out of the question. After some searching around the web, I found some code and implemented it into mine - here is m current code - this is just a countdown to test the waiting:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_flash);

    // ALL THIS STUFF IS AUTO-GENERATED
    final View controlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
    final View contentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);

    // Set up an instance of SystemUiHider to control the system UI for
    // this activity.
    mSystemUiHider = SystemUiHider.getInstance(this, contentView, HIDER_FLAGS);
    mSystemUiHider.setup();
    mSystemUiHider
            .setOnVisibilityChangeListener(new SystemUiHider.OnVisibilityChangeListener() {
                // Cached values.
                int mControlsHeight;
                int mShortAnimTime;

                @Override
                @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
                public void onVisibilityChange(boolean visible) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
                        // If the ViewPropertyAnimator API is available
                        // (Honeycomb MR2 and later), use it to animate the
                        // in-layout UI controls at the bottom of the
                        // screen.
                        if (mControlsHeight == 0) {
                            mControlsHeight = controlsView.getHeight();
                        }
                        if (mShortAnimTime == 0) {
                            mShortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(
                                    android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
                        }
                        controlsView.animate()
                                .translationY(visible ? 0 : mControlsHeight)
                                .setDuration(mShortAnimTime);
                    } else {
                        // If the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs aren't
                        // available, simply show or hide the in-layout UI
                        // controls.
                        controlsView.setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
                    }

                    if (visible && AUTO_HIDE) {
                        // Schedule a hide().
                        delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
                    }
                }
            });

    // Set up the user interaction to manually show or hide the system UI.
    contentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (TOGGLE_ON_CLICK) {
                mSystemUiHider.toggle();
            } else {
                mSystemUiHider.show();
            }
        }
    });

    // Upon interacting with UI controls, delay any scheduled hide()
    // operations to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
    // while interacting with the UI.


    // EVERYTHING UP TO HERE IS AUTO-GENERATED
    final TextView currentLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.labelCurrent);
    final TextView totalLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.labelTotal);

    new Thread () {
        public void run() {
            currentLabel.setText("3");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            currentLabel.setText("2");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            currentLabel.setText("1");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
        }
    }.start();
}
```

When testing this code, I found that in the emulated AVD, it just goes straight back to the MainActivity, and when I generated an APK and tested it on my device, the app crashed.

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT 1- Here's the logcat:**

```
08-09 15:42:29.054    2012-2012/com.example.nat.morseflasher D/gralloc_goldfish﹕ Emulator without GPU emulation detected.

08-09 15:42:38.564    2012-2012/com.example.nat.morseflasher D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 143K, 8% free 3195K/3444K, paused 142ms, total 183ms
08-09 15:42:55.654    2012-2012/com.example.nat.morseflasher I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-09 15:42:56.294    2012-2012/com.example.nat.morseflasher I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 47 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-09 15:43:07.725    2012-2012/com.example.nat.morseflasher I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 1159 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

**EDIT 2:**

Ok, so I've implemented the code you provided into mine, although I changed some things so it fits with how I want it.

When I try to run this, the log shows the "Starting morse code flasher..." message, but it never gets to the printing letter or symbol parts. When I tap the ready button, nothing changes at all, and it just goes back to the main activity as defined in the onPostExecute function.

Here's the XML:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0099cc"
    tools:context="com.example.nat.morseflasher.FlashActivity">

    <!-- The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
         is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
         TextureView, etc. -->
    <TextView android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:textColor="#33b5e5"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/dummy_content"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <!-- This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
         android:fitsSystemWindows. -->
    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"
        style="?metaButtonBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/black_overlay"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="-"
        android:id="@+id/labelCurrent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:textSize="100sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Ready?"
        android:id="@+id/labelTotal"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/tapToGo"
        android:id="@+id/buttonGo"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
        android:onClick="doMorse" />

    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Here's the java:

```
package com.example.nat.morseflasher;

import com.example.nat.morseflasher.util.SystemUiHider;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * An example full-screen activity that shows and hides the system UI (i.e.
 * status bar and navigation/system bar) with user interaction.
 *
 * @see SystemUiHider
 */
public class FlashActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Whether or not the system UI should be auto-hidden after
     * {@link #AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS} milliseconds.
     */
    private static final boolean AUTO_HIDE = true;

    /**
     * If {@link #AUTO_HIDE} is set, the number of milliseconds to wait after
     * user interaction before hiding the system UI.
     */
    private static final int AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;

    /**
     * If set, will toggle the system UI visibility upon interaction. Otherwise,
     * will show the system UI visibility upon interaction.
     */
    private static final boolean TOGGLE_ON_CLICK = true;

    /**
     * The flags to pass to {@link SystemUiHider#getInstance}.
     */
    private static final int HIDER_FLAGS = SystemUiHider.FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;

    /**
     * The instance of the {@link SystemUiHider} for this activity.
     */
    private SystemUiHider mSystemUiHider;

    private final static String TAG = "FlashActivity";

    private final static long TIME_UNIT = 250L;
    private final static long ONE_SECOND = 1000L;
    private final static long DOT_DELAY = TIME_UNIT;
    private final static long DASH_DELAY = TIME_UNIT * 2;
    private final static long INTRA_LETTER_DELAY = TIME_UNIT;
    private final static long INTER_LETTER_DELAY = TIME_UNIT * 2;
    private final static long INTER_WORD_DELAY = TIME_UNIT * 6;

    Button goButton;
    FrameLayout layoutFrame;
    TextView currentLabel, totalLabel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_flash);

        final View controlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
        final View contentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);

        // Set up an instance of SystemUiHider to control the system UI for
        // this activity.
        mSystemUiHider = SystemUiHider.getInstance(this, contentView, HIDER_FLAGS);
        mSystemUiHider.setup();
        mSystemUiHider
            .setOnVisibilityChangeListener(new SystemUiHider.OnVisibilityChangeListener() {
                    // Cached values.
                    int mControlsHeight;
                    int mShortAnimTime;

                    @Override
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
                    public void onVisibilityChange(boolean visible) {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
                            // If the ViewPropertyAnimator API is available
                            // (Honeycomb MR2 and later), use it to animate the
                            // in-layout UI controls at the bottom of the
                            // screen.
                            if (mControlsHeight == 0) {
                                mControlsHeight = controlsView.getHeight();
                            }
                            if (mShortAnimTime == 0) {
                                mShortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(
                                        android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
                            }
                            controlsView.animate()
                                    .translationY(visible ? 0 : mControlsHeight)
                                    .setDuration(mShortAnimTime);
                        } else {
                            // If the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs aren't
                            // available, simply show or hide the in-layout UI
                            // controls.
                            controlsView.setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
                        }

                        if (visible && AUTO_HIDE) {
                            // Schedule a hide().
                            delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
                        }
                    }
                });

        // Set up the user interaction to manually show or hide the system UI.
        contentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (TOGGLE_ON_CLICK) {
                    mSystemUiHider.toggle();
                } else {
                    mSystemUiHider.show();
                }
            }
        });

        goButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonGo);
        layoutFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);
        currentLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.labelCurrent);
        totalLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.labelTotal);
        // Upon interacting with UI controls, delay any scheduled hide()
        // operations to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
        // while interacting with the UI.

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Trigger the initial hide() shortly after the activity has been
        // created, to briefly hint to the user that UI controls
        // are available.
        delayedHide(100);
    }


    /**
     * Touch listener to use for in-layout UI controls to delay hiding the
     * system UI. This is to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
     * while interacting with activity UI.
     */
    View.OnTouchListener mDelayHideTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (AUTO_HIDE) {
                delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
    Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mSystemUiHider.hide();
        }
    };

    /**
     * Schedules a call to hide() in [delay] milliseconds, canceling any
     * previously scheduled calls.
     */
    private void delayedHide(int delayMillis) {
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, delayMillis);
    }

    public void doMorse(View vw) {
        goButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        (new DoMorseFlashing()).execute();
    }

    private class DoMorseFlashing extends AsyncTask <String, Boolean, Void> {

        SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("MorseFlasher", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String msgStr, currentLetterMorse;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... message) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Starting Morse Code flasher...");
            msgStr = mPrefs.getString("prevMsg", "");
            String totalStr = "";

            /*currentLabel.setText("3");
             *doDelay(ONE_SECOND);
             *currentLabel.setText("2");
             *doDelay(ONE_SECOND);
             *currentLabel.setText("1");
             *doDelay(ONE_SECOND);
             */
            for(int i=0; i<msgStr.length(); i++) {
                if(msgStr.charAt(i)=='|') {
                    doDelay(INTER_WORD_DELAY);
                }
                else {
                    currentLetterMorse = convert(msgStr.charAt(i));

                    currentLabel.setText(msgStr.substring(i, i + 1));

                    totalStr += msgStr.substring(i, i + 1);
                    totalLabel.setText(totalStr);

                    Log.v(TAG, " flashing letter " + msgStr.charAt(i) + " with morse code " + currentLetterMorse + ":");
                    for (int j = 0; j < currentLetterMorse.length(); j++) {
                        Log.v(TAG, "flashing symbol " + currentLetterMorse.charAt(j) + ":");
                        flash(currentLetterMorse.charAt(j));
                        doDelay(INTRA_LETTER_DELAY);
                    }
                    doDelay(INTER_LETTER_DELAY);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // Set the button message back to "touch here" to indicate that were done flashing:
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
        }

        void flash(char letter) {
            layoutFrame.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            currentLabel.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            totalLabel.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            switch (letter) {
                case '.':
                    doDelay(DOT_DELAY);
                case '-':
                    doDelay(DASH_DELAY);
            }
            layoutFrame.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            currentLabel.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            totalLabel.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        }

        String convert(char letter){
            switch (letter){
                case 'a':
                    return ".-";
                case 'b':
                    return "-…";
                case 'c':
                    return "-.-.";
                case 'd':
                    return "-..";
                case 'e':
                    return ".";
                case 'f':
                    return "..-.";
                case 'g':
                    return "--.";
                case 'h':
                    return "….";
                case 'i':
                    return "..";
                case 'j':
                    return ".---";
                case 'k':
                    return "-.-";
                case 'l':
                    return ".-..";
                case 'm':
                    return "--";
                case 'n':
                    return "-.";
                case 'o':
                    return "---";
                case 'p':
                    return ".--.";
                case 'q':
                    return "--.-";
                case 'r':
                    return ".-.";
                case 's':
                    return "...";
                case 't':
                    return "-";
                case 'u':
                    return "..-";
                case 'v':
                    return "...-";
                case 'w':
                    return ".--";
                case 'x':
                    return "-..-";
                case 'y':
                    return "-.--";
                case 'z':
                    return "--..";
                case ' ':
                    return "|";
                default:
                    return "|";
            }
        }

        void doDelay(Long delay) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(delay);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // Ignore interruptions
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the LogCat:

```
08-10 18:30:43.856    2090-2090/com.example.nat.morseflasher D/gralloc_goldfish﹕ Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
08-10 18:30:46.146    2090-2106/com.example.nat.morseflasher D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 146K, 8% free 3192K/3448K, paused 31ms, total 39ms
08-10 18:30:50.816    2090-2090/com.example.nat.morseflasher I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 464 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-10 18:31:04.116    2090-2090/com.example.nat.morseflasher I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 69 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-10 18:31:06.486    2090-2090/com.example.nat.morseflasher I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 62 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-10 18:31:11.176    2090-2090/com.example.nat.morseflasher I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-10 18:31:11.937    2090-2106/com.example.nat.morseflasher V/FlashActivity﹕ Starting Morse Code flasher...
08-10 18:31:13.437    2090-2090/com.example.nat.morseflasher I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 109 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

**EDIT 3:**
Ok, so the earlier problem was due to the fact that it wasn't retrieving my string from SharedPreferences, so just to make sure everything else worked, I set the message string to "test" in the code. Now, the problem is that when it goes to change the colour of the screen, I get an error saying that only the main thread that created the view hierarchy can touch its views.

**EDIT 4:**
I've fixed the error as aforementioned by using runOnUiThread() when I go to change the screen and text colours, the flashing now works!

Comment: print logcat into ur question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LogCat messages are telling you that your app is spending too much time on the main thread and starving the GUI of processing time.

If all you want to do is flash the screen, you could use a simple [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) rather than all the complexity of your `SystemUiHider`.

Here's some code that shows how a background AsyncTask could be used using simple thread-sleeps to handle the timing. Since it's a background task, the sleeping won't interfere with the main GUI thread.

The main feature is that `publishProgess()` is called periodically to turn the flasher on or off.  Note you can't make GUI changes from within the `doInBackground()` method stack, but can within the onProgessUpdate() and onPostExecute() ones. I used the same button for both starting and showing the flashing so that I could demonstrate using the `onPostExecute()` method to reset the button text.

You'll obviously need to add Morse code strings for the other letters and probably tweak the timing values to get things to look right.

## MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.com;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // String for LogCat documentation
    private final static String TAG = "MainActivity";

    // These define the lengths for the dots, dashes, and times in between:
    private final static long TIME_UNIT = 250L;
    private final static long DOT_DELAY = TIME_UNIT * 2;
    private final static long DASH_DELAY = TIME_UNIT * 3;
    private final static long INTRA_LETTER_DELAY = TIME_UNIT;
    private final static long INTER_LETTER_DELAY = TIME_UNIT * 3;
    private final static long INTER_WORD_DELAY = TIME_UNIT * 7;

    private Button flasher = null;
    private EditText message = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        flasher = (Button) findViewById(R.id.flasher);
        message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message);
    }

    public void doMorse(View vw) {
        String messageStr = message.getText().toString();
        if (messageStr.length() > 0) {

            // This creates and starts a background task to do the flashing:
            (new DoMorseFlashing()).execute(messageStr);

            // Set the button message to indicate that we're flashing a message:
            flasher.setText(R.string.flashing_message);
        }
    }

    private class DoMorseFlashing extends AsyncTask <String, Boolean, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... message) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Starting Morse Code flasher...");

            for (char letter : message[0].toCharArray()) {
                if (letter == ' ')
                    doDelay(INTER_WORD_DELAY);
                else
                    showLetter(letter);
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Boolean... flasherOn) {
            if (flasherOn[0])
                flasher.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            else
                flasher.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // Set the button message back to "touch here" to indicate that we're done flashing:
            flasher.setText(R.string.touch_here);
        }

        void showLetter(char letter) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Flashing code for " + letter);

            switch (letter) {
                case 'A': showMorse(".-"); break;
                case 'B': showMorse("-..."); break;
                case 'C': showMorse("-.-."); break;

                // cases for the other letters...

                default: /* skip character */
            }

            doDelay(INTER_LETTER_DELAY);
        }

        void showMorse(String morse) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Flashing code " + morse);

            for (char dotDash: morse.toCharArray()) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Flashing " + dotDash);

                publishProgress(true);

                if (dotDash == '.')
                    doDelay(DOT_DELAY);
                else
                    doDelay(DASH_DELAY);

                doDelay(INTRA_LETTER_DELAY);
                publishProgress(false);
            }
        }

        void doDelay(Long delay) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(delay);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // Ignore interruptions
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
        android:hint="@string/enter_message" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/flasher"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="top|center"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:hint="@string/touch_here"
        android:onClick="doMorse" />

</LinearLayout>
```

## strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Morse Flasher</string>    
    <string name="enter_message">Enter message</string>
    <string name="touch_here">Touch here to flash message</string>
    <string name="flashing_message">Flashing message</string>

</resources>
```

Comment: Ok, I've tried your code with quite a few modifications, although it seems that there is no change after tapping the start button, before just going back to the MainActivity (as defined in the onPostExecute method). See my edit for details.

Comment: I'm not sure what the `SystemUiHider` stuff is doing or whether it's causing any problems, but I see that it is doing stuff with Handlers, which is another way of multi-threading. But I also see that you're not using the normal inputs to the AsyncTask (in this case named "message"), but are instead using something from SharedPreferences. I suggest putting a bunch of logging to validate your inputs and to see what's happening at each step.

Comment: I found the error with SharedPreferences - the code in my FlashActivity is completely fine, it's just that I forgot to put commit() in another activity which saves the user's input to SharedPreferences. I've sorted all my problems out with the code. Thank you so much of your help!